# Get all three digit numbers from array and store in new array

Tags: ruby, regex

I need a regular expression that only matches three digit numbers in the following array. I need the result to be a new array.

Input:

```
my_array = [111,45456,456,74897,787,45466,789,6587,784,234,456,4658,4587,235,456]
```

Desired output:

```
new_array = [111,456,787,789,784,234,456,235,456]
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Your sentence is incomprehensible.

Comment: How can a regex match  numbers?

Comment: I want only three digit numbers like 111 456 787 789 784 234 456 235 456 only from the above array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why regular expression on numbers? You can select all numbers less than 1000 and greater than 99.

```
my_array.select { |n| n<1000 && n>99 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just the regexp would look like this: `/^\d{3}$/`. But if you'd like an expression that would return an array of values that match that expression this would do it: `my_array.select{ |num| num.to_s.match(/^\d{3}$/) }`.

Take a look at [RegExr](http://www.regexr.com) to learn more about Regular Expressions.

Comment: You're welcome kirankumar, I'm glad that I could help.

Comment: Thank you Taylor but i used this one i get all three elements in over all array. Like below 111,454,456,748,787,454,789,658,784,234,456,465,458,235,456.                  but i need only three digit numbers.

Comment: Thank you Taylor it is Best one